# Adding a config file to loop through for a PS script

Tags: powershell

My powershell script is setup as follows:

```
$body =  Get-ChildItem E:\log -File -Recurse | Where Name -Match '(\d{8})\.' | 
    Foreach {Add-Member -Inp $_ NoteProperty ReturnDate ($matches[1]) -PassThru} | 
    Group DirectoryName | 
    Foreach {$_.Group | Sort ReturnDate -Desc | Select -First 1 | Out-String }


$emailSmtpServer = "server"
$emailFrom = "email"
$emailTo = "email"
$emailSubject = "Testing e-mail"
$emailBody = $body


Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $emailSubject -Body ($body|Out-String) -SmtpServer $emailSmtpServer
```

In the log folder I have a bunch of subfolders, e.g. folder1, folder2, folder3. These are likely to change so I'd like to setup a config file to be able to maintain them instead of going through the entire E:\log folder each time I run the script.

I want to add something such as

```
$configfile = Get-Content -path E:\config.txt
```

This outputs Process1, Process2, Process3, etc and I'm uncertain how to put that data into my script the way it's currently structured. Any advice would be appreciated. I was trying to add

```
$body = Get-Childitem E:\log\$_
```

to my initial line, but that was not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
get-childitem ( get-content e:/config.txt )
```